# How to toggle fullscreen in Emacs GUI mode (`Full Screen` option is greyed out in Kubuntu)?

Tags: frames, integration, linux

This is such a basic question but I am really at a loss (a google search only revealed solutions for OS X).

Until recently, I primarily used terminal mode (which I can make full-screen using my desktop environment's full-screen shortcut for the shell window) but switched to GUI because I'd like to be able to pick a font.

Any suggestions?  Maximizing using the buttons in the window title bar doesn't go to true full screen - I can still see the task bar and the window title bar.

Edit: I should add that the `Full-screen` option (i.e., after right-clicking the window title bar) is greyed out (see exhibit 1 below).  Also, changing the `Full Screen` setting under `Special Applications Settings` automatically reverts to being disabled.

The `No border` option does offer a partial solution in that it makes the window title bar disappear (though task bar is still visible) - it would be nice if there was a way to easily toggle full-screen using a keyboard shortcut and given KDE's and emacs' customizability, I think it's probaby due to my being a KDE and emacs n00b.

---

Exhibit 1:

[image]

---

**Update:**

In order to safeguard against any settings I may have inadvertently customized, I ended up resetting my kde desktop (by deleting the relevant plasma file).  Upon reboot, I was able to use the `Special Window Settings` dialog box to `Force` the application into full-screen mode (the dialog box is accessed by invoking the menu via `Alt+F3` -> `More actions` -> `Special window settings`).  (Screenshot below.)

In a general sense, **I still prefer paprika's answer which involves creating a global keyboard shortcut** as it's the better solution.   Just wanted to include my roundabout fix in case other folks also find that their emacs is refusing to accept the `full screen` global keyboard shortcut.

Forcing full-screen mode from the `Special Window Settings` dialog box:

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

GNU Emacs has built-in support for fullscreen since version 24.4.  From the changelog:

> New commands `toggle-frame-fullscreen` and `toggle-frame-maximized`,
>   bound to `<f11>` and `M-<f10>`, respectively.

Note that you don't need to use the latest Emacs version just for this feature.  Your window manager (KDE/KWin) is able to put any application window into fullscreen mode, [as explained here](https://askubuntu.com/a/522891).

Comment: Yeah, I'd added (i) `Shift + F11` as a `global keyboard shortcut` bound to `Map to all fullscreen` and (ii) `F11` as a `standard keyboard shortcut` bound to `Full Screen Mode` but neither of those is working.   It's odd that the the `Full-screen` option is greyed out in the menu-bar (i.e., the menu that comes up after right-clicking the title bar of the emacs window).

Answer (score 4):

The [instructions on emacswiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen) worked for me (Emacs 24.3.1).
I've only tried this on Unity, so I'm not 100% sure it will work on KDE. Here's the relevant portion from my ~/.emacs:

```
(defun my-fullscreen ()
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 'fullboth) ;this makes the frame go fullscreen
  (tool-bar-mode -1) ;these 3 lines turn off GUI junk
  (scroll-bar-mode -1)
  (menu-bar-mode -1))

(defun my-non-fullscreen ()
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-parameter nil 'width 82)
  (set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 'fullheight)
  (menu-bar-mode t)) ;I don't turn tool-bar and scroll-bar back on b/c I never want them

(defun toggle-fullscreen ()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq (frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen) 'fullboth)  ;tests if already fullscreened
      (my-non-fullscreen)
    (my-fullscreen)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f11>") 'toggle-fullscreen)
```